# Print row as many times as its value plus one turns up in other rows

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, rows

I want to print each row in a new df (df2) according to how many times its imageno+1 turns up. So in the data below, row 1 should be printed twice (there are two 7s), row 2 twice, row 3 twice, row 4 once (there is one 8), row 5 once, etc.

```
import pandas as pd

print(df)
   x-position  y-position  imageno
1  220         220          6
2  627         220          6
3  620         220          6
4  220         220          7
5  628         220          7
6  621         220          8

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x-position', 'y-position', 'imageno'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `merge` after adjust the `'imageno'`

```
df.assign(imageno=df.imageno+1).merge(df[['imageno']],on='imageno').assign(imageno=lambda x : x['imageno']-1)
Out[894]: 
   x-position  y-position  imageno
0         220         220        6
1         220         220        6
2         627         220        6
3         627         220        6
4         620         220        6
5         620         220        6
6         220         220        7
7         628         220        7
```

Comment: Thanks. This works (no error messages) but I think the imagenos are one higher than they should be?

Comment: This worked, thank you. Is it possible to explain the code please?

Comment: @sforbes add one , so when merger (6+1) will merge with 7, then after the merge we just need subtract one , go back to original

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, create a helper series using [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), [`index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to get the desired number or repetitions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x-position': {1: 220, 2: 627, 3: 620, 4: 220, 5: 628, 6: 621}, 'y-position': {1: 220, 2: 220, 3: 220, 4: 220, 5: 220, 6: 220}, 'imageno': {1: 6, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 7, 5: 7, 6: 8}})

s = df['imageno'].value_counts()

df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['imageno'].add(1).map(s).fillna(0).astype(int))]
```

[out]

```
   x-position  y-position  imageno
1         220         220        6
1         220         220        6
2         627         220        6
2         627         220        6
3         620         220        6
3         620         220        6
4         220         220        7
5         628         220        7
```

Comment: Thanks. I got an error `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`. Do you know how I could fix this please?

Comment: @sforbes hmmmm, are you getting the EOF if you copy and paste the above code including sample data..? Maybe your missing closing parenthesis or closing quotes somewhere?

Comment: Does the error message give a hint to where the SyntaxError is in the code? What line, what column etc?

Comment: Thanks for the sample data. With the code you sent I get the error `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`

Comment: I cant reproduce that error, maybe a versioning issue..? I updated the code, adding in `astype(int)` method. Could you try it again?